# Comparing two string in if condition, one of them is $line - SHELL script

Tags: shell

I have got a problem with something like this:

```
while read line
do
       if [ "$line" == "<main>:" ]; then
       OBJ=$line
       fi
       echo "$OBJ goes to $line"
done < temp > file
```

I need to filter all the strings which has '>:' in the end (instead of <'main>:' only), but no regular expressions works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to filter all the strings which has '>:' in the end

You can use this in BASH:

```
[[ "$line" == *">:" ]]
```

Comment: Oh, I don't know why it's this, but it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is called glob patten. `*">:"` means anything followed by `>:` in the end.